How to send a bot a command via url?
I'm trying to send the bot a command with arguments via url I've seen solutions like this: https://t.me/_bot?start=my_data, but it doesn't work for me and just follows the link to the bot.
Please write how to correctly generate the url for my task, and whether an additional handler is needed for this in the code

what bot? What command? maybe you have wrong code in bot - but we can't see your code, and we can read in your mind - so we can't help you. You have to show all details in question (not in comments). And don't expect that we will write all code for you.

The user views the qr code sent to him by the bot. In the qr code link to the bot in this form https://t.me/mybot?getreward=id_reward, and then he should supposedly click on the link and the bot will send this command. The link to the bot I can not provide in this sorry. And yes the code is correct, I just want to click on this link to send a command to the bot, but on my devices the link is just redirect to my bot.

I don't trust your code.

@furas I just want to understand why the diplink isn't working. What does this have to do with the code?

as I remember telegram allows only for start=parameters but not getreward=id_reward. And you have to create command /start which will get parameters in update.message.text as text /start paremeter1 parameter2 or in context.args as list ['parameter1', 'parameter2']. And it displays button START which user has to click.

Maybe you have to send it as string getreward-id_reward in start=getreward-id_reward and in command start split on -. OR you can convert dict {"getreward": id_reward} to base64 and in command start use module base64.decode() to JSON string and later json.loads() to convert this JSON string to dictionary

Deep links - Bot links

For t.me/<bot> you can use only some values - like start=, game=
See doc: Deep links - Bot links

If you use start=params then it switches to your bot
and it executes command /start params
and it shows button START which user has to click.
If you use empty start= or start then it switches to your bot
but it doesn't executes command /start.
So you may need to put all information after start= like
https://t.me/mybot?start=getreward-id_reward

and in command start you can use - to split getreward-id_reward
But... there is another problem. It allows only for some chars in parameters - for example it doesn't allow for + or space - so it may need to convert data to string base64
(BTW: base64 allows to use + but telegram may have problem with + so it may need to use urlsafe_b64encode() instead of popular b64encode())
import base64

text = '++ hello world ++'
text_base64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(text.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')

print(f'https://t.me/mybot?start={text_base64}')

and later
async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    #print('text:', update.message.text)   # /start something
    #print('args:', context.args)          # ['something']

    text_base64 = context.args[0]
    text = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(text_base64.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')

    print('text:', text)    

    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=f"start params: {text}")


If you want to send something more complex (like list or dict) then you may use json
import base64
import json

data = {'method': 'xyz', 'id': 1234}
text_json = json.dumps(data)
text_base64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(text_json.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')

print(f'https://t.me/furasbot?start={text_base64}')

and later
async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    #print('text:', update.message.text)   # /start something
    #print('args:', context.args)          # ['something']

    text_base64 = context.args[0]
    text_json = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(text_base64.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    data = json.loads(text_json)
    
    print('data:', data)   
    print('keys:', data.keys())   
    print('method:', data['method'])   
    print('    id:', data['id'])   
 
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=f"start method: {data['method'}, id: {data['id']")


EDIT:
Minimal working code for tests (with python-telegram-bot):
import os
import logging
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import filters, ApplicationBuilder, ContextTypes, CommandHandler, MessageHandler
import base64
import json

def generate_link(text=None, data=None, b64=True, botname='<bot_name>'):
        
    if text:
        if b64:
            output = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(text.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
        else:
            output = text
        print(f'text: https://t.me/{botname}?start={output}')
        
    if data:
        text = json.dumps(data)
        output = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(text.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')

        print(f'data: https://t.me/{botname}?start={output}')

generate_link(botname='furasbot', text='hello-world', b64=False)
generate_link(botname='furasbot', text='hello world')
generate_link(botname='furasbot', data={'method': 'xyz', 'id': 1234})

# ----------------------------------

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    print('text:', update.message.text)   # /start something
    print('args:', context.args)          # ['something']
    #text = str(context.args)
    
    text_base64 = context.args[0]
    
    try:
        text = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(text_base64.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    except Exception as e:   # binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
        print('Exception:', e)
        text = text_base64
        
    try:
        data = json.loads(text)
    except Exception as e:   # json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
        print('Exception:', e)
        data = dict()
        
    print('text:', text)    
    print('data:', data)
    print('keys:', data.keys())
    for key, val in data.items():
        print(f'> {key} = {val}')
    
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=f"start params: {text}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).build()
    
    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
    application.add_handler(start_handler)
    
    application.run_polling() 

Some links:
https://t.me/<bot_name>?start=hello-world
https://t.me/<bot_name>?start=aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=
https://t.me/<bot_name>?start=eyJtZXRob2QiOiAieHl6IiwgImlkIjogMTIzNH0=

